# 文章の話題語の変化はどう解釈されていますか？

Tags: particle-は, composition

日本語では、話題語がとても重要だと考えられていると思います。文章で話題語がなければ、ほとんどの人には不自然、もしくは不快に聞こえると思います。

しかし、文章が一文より長い場合、話題語の選択は私にはかなり難しくなります。話題語をいつ変えればいいかがいつもよく分かりません。普段、直感的に選びますが、母語話者じゃありませんので、かなり危険なやり方だと思います。したがって、ある種の指針を求めています。

---

実例を用いて説明します。

> 前半では、主人公が龍を倒す。後半では、龍が復活し、また勇者に倒される。

話題語が変化しないようにちょっと書き直すと

> 主人公は、前半で龍を倒す。後半で復活した龍をまた倒す。

私には前者の文章のほうが自然に感じると思いますが、後者は間違っているというわけでもないですね。後者はもっと端的に本を説明しているような気がします。そして、後者のほうが短いです。

私の印象はさておき、この単純な２文にさまざまなバリエーションがあるのは間違いないです。ほとんどの文章はこうやって変えられると思います。このバリエーションからどう選択すればいいですか？

---

具体例とともに、このような原則があるのでしょうか。（適当に思い付いたんですけど。)

- 「話題語を複数の文にわたって変えないようにせよ。」
- 「短くすることに集中しすぎるな。そのかわり、話題語を適切な印象を残すように選べ。」

複雑なテーマだと分かっていますが、何かの基準や指針があれば、教えてください。

Comment: 「前半の主人公は太郎だが、後半には次郎に変わる。」というバリエーションもありますね。

Comment: 例文の「てにをは」も変えていいですか？

Comment: @Choko もちろん問題ないです。

Comment: I don't think this problem is specific to Japanese. In either language I feel these example sentences would sound better when glued together with a conjunction: "In the first half Taro is the protagonist, but in the second half Jiro steals the show." or "While Taro seems to be the lead role in the first half, Jiro turns out to be the protagonist of the second half." or whatever.

Comment: 読解力に欠けているせいか、正直いまひとつ質問の趣旨がわかりかねます。

Comment: @Will Depends on what you mean by "this problem". Information structure is definitely complex in any language, but I think Japanese has unique challenges due to their being the extra "thematic" element in the sentences. I just figured there must be some sort of guidance people receive in writing class or style guides or something regarding this.

Comment: By any chance, isn't this question about "subject ≒ 主語" in grammar, rather than "topic ≒ 主題 ≒ 話題"? 主語 and 話題 are completely different things.

Comment: @Choko 訂正した例文、たしかに前より自然だけど、話題が何なのかわからなくなりました…「前半では、主人公は太郎だ」の話題は、「前半」ではなく「主人公」かな。そうだとしたら、前の「は」は対照の助詞というわけですね…しかし、たしかに話題としても使えるような気が…「前半では、大きな龍が勇者に倒され、民族がその勝利を祝う。また、本当の悪人が登場し、後半の準備を整える。」って感じかな。質問の例文を間違えたんでしょう…

Comment: @naruto I don't know my Japanese terms perfectly, but in grammar, doesn't 主語 only refer to things which are syntactically the subject of the sentence?　While the topic is sometimes the subject, I don't think it always is. Is there a less ambiguous term for the grammatical topic?

Comment: @非回答者 いいえ、趣旨がわかりにくいのせいでしょう。質問を直せるかどうかは分からないけど、もう少し考えて手を加えます。

Comment: You're correct, 主語 specifically refers to grammatical "subject" in a sentence, while 話題 is "topic" in much broader sense. "話題の変化" refers to the complete change of topics in a conversation (eg "今日は雨ですね。ところで、好きな食べ物は何ですか?"). In your 太郎/次郎 example, I think there is no "話題の変化" at all, which confuses me.

Comment: @naruto Yes, I definitely do not mean that sort of 話題の変化, I just mean the thing being marked by 「は」 changing. Maybe 話題語 is better?

Comment: 例文を要点を明確にするように書き直そうとしました。「てにをは」はまた間違っているなら、教えてください。

Comment: 多分broad過ぎると思いますので、closeに投票しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

他言語と比較した場合、日本語において話題語が特に重要であることは事実だと思います。

その大きな要因としては、英語などと異なり、文の主語が多くの場合に省略されるという文法的な特徴があるからだと思います。また、スペイン語のように、日本語と同様に文の主語が頻繁に省略されはするものの、動詞の中で主語に当たる代名詞を明示することのできる言語とも明らかに構造的に異なっています。

要するに、誇張した言い方をすれば、日本語の場合は、話題語が物理的に『勝手に』読者の目や耳に飛び込んでくる言語ではないということが言えるのではないでしょうか。サブジェクトプロミネントな英語などと異なり、日本語はトピックプロミネントなんですね。

この相違点が、日常の会話からある程度「正式な」文章までに与える影響は小さくありません。話題の維持・変更をスムーズに行いにくい、あるいは行うのにテクニックが必要になるのが日本語なのかもしれません。

正直に言えば、未だにDJさんの質問の趣旨が完璧には理解できていないのですが、恐らくこのあたりのことについて聞かれているのでは、と思いながら書いています。もし的外れな回答であれば読み流してください。

> 1) 前半では、主人公が龍を倒す。後半では、龍が復活し、また勇者に倒される。
>
> 2) 主人公は、前半で龍を倒す。後半で復活した龍をまた倒す。

個人的には2番の方が良いかと思います。

1番は、主語が「主人公」から「龍」に変わっています。従って、最後に受身形を使用しています。つまり、主語を変えてしまったために、「能動態」と「受動態」の両方を使用せざる得なくなってしまったわけですね。この事が文章の流れを悪くしているような気がします。読者に小さなストレスを与えていると言いましょうか。こういう小さなストレスが積もった時に、「この人の文章、読みにくい」という印象をもたれてしまう危険性が出てくるのです。

2番に関しては、一文にまとめて、「主人公は、前半で龍を倒し、後半では復活した龍を再び倒す。」とするとよりスッキリするかと思います。

獅子のような顔をして、指針を述べても似合いませんが（ここは必ず突っ込むべし）、最後に一言。

> 「話題語を複数の文にわたって変えないようにせよ。」

おっしゃる通りです。話題語はあまり変えていかない方が無難かと思います。上述したように、話題語自体が主語になる場合、省略されてしまうことが多く、話題語を直接使用する機会自体が英語などよりは少ないので、少ない機会の中で何度も変更すると読みにくい文章になります。

> 「短くすることに集中しすぎるな。そのかわり、話題語を適切な印象を残すように選べ。」

これは名言です。コンパクトなら必ずいいというものではありません。

Comment: 曖昧な質問にご回答しいただき本当にありがとうございます！前置き・文の解説・感想が全部非常に役立つと思います！顔が獅子のようではなく紳士のようだと言わざるを得ません！